# Play animation with Xbox controller

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, controller, xbox

I am making a 2d game that can use either the keyboard or an Xbox One controller as movement.

So far, I can move the players and play a running animation, jump animation etc using the keyboard, and I can move using the Xbox controller.

However, I can't play animations with the Xbox controller.

I have this:

```
void Update()
{
    movement.x = Input.GetAxis("LeftJoystickX") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Orange player movement
            if (orange)
            {
                transform.position += movement;

                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                {
                    ChangeDirection("right");
                    ChangeState(STATE_RUN);
                    transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                    if (!onGround)
                        ChangeState(STATE_JUMP);
                }
            }
}
```

Here, if you use the keyboard, the animations play. If you use the controller, the player moves but the animations don't play. I've **tried** and narrowed it down to the fact that this piece of code will not evaluate:

`if (Input.GetAxis("LeftJoystickX"))`

as `Input.GetAxis()` returns a float and not a bool (?) and therefore cannot be put in an `if` statement.

I guess what I am asking is, is it possible to detect a direction of a Joystick push from a controller, such as something like `Input.GetAxis().joystickPushedRight`?

Or better yet, is there a different way I could execute

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            ChangeDirection("right");
            ChangeState(STATE_RUN);
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            if (!onGround)
                ChangeState(STATE_JUMP);
        }
```

But use the joystick instead of `Input.GetKey`?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the joystick might not be perfectly calibrated, so you'll want to ignore values that are close to zero by some threshold.

Comment: Ah that's brilliant! @rene, if you post your comment as an answer, with SimpleVar 's comment put in I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Input.GetAxis](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) returns a float between -1 and 1.

If you take that into account together with a [threshold for values close to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982620/play-animation-with-xbox-controller?noredirect=1#comment55721284_33982620) you can determine if you need to go up or down or need to stop.

Your implementation will look like this:

```
const float threshold = 0.05;
const string axis = "LeftJoystickX";
if (Input.GetAxis(axis) < -threshold)
{
  //go left
} 
else if (Input.GetAxis(axis) > threshold) 
{
   //go right
} 
else 
{
   // don't move
}
```